# Serve response right away then do subsequent processing in controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an endpoint that consumes POST requests, logs relevant info from the request, then responds with a 200 OK. It's important that it respond quickly, and processing the log entry can take some time, so I'm wondering if I can change this:

```
def my_endpoint
  generate_log_entry
  render nothing: true
end
```

to this:

```
def my_endpoint
  render nothing: true
  generate_log_entry
end
```

I'm pretty sure I cannot -- I think the call to `render` just builds the response for serving later in the Rack middleware lifecycle. Is delegating the logging to an async process my only option?

Comment: Nutshell, yes: if you have a long-running process you don't want it involved in the request processing pipeline regardless of whether or not the response is sent right away or not--it's still stuck in that method until the method is done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have this option, the action will be executed after it renders the view, but before it sends the response. So the response time will be affected.

```
class YourController < ApplicationController
  after_action :generate_log_entry, only: :my_endpoint
  
  #your stuffs
end
```

---

So I think it's better to delegating the logging to an async process, you can use library like `sucker_punch`.